# Does a static final Object ever get deleted by Garbage Collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have previously used Custom Objects in a Service in Java that always keeps running at the back end and I have sometimes got Bug reports with traces that showed `NULL_POINTER_EXCEPTION` as the object was destroyed by the Garbage Collector. As I have all high end devices I am unable to test this that does a static final object get destroyed by the garbage collector or not?

Comment: Why do you have tags C++ and C#?

Comment: You forgot the Visual Basic tag...

Comment: "Custom object service", "high-end devices" - what platform is this? is this specifically the Android JVM?

Comment: If this is about Android, as @Rup suggested, the way to test this is clearing the RAM while running your app (this is equivalent to Android killing your process when it feels like it). I had huge problems in my app, because my static objects were destroyed unexpectedly.

Comment: @Rup Yes the issue was on an Android Applciation but i belive this is not a Android specific Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a static final Object ever get deleted by Garbage Collector?

I can think of three circumstances where this could happen:

1. The classloader that loaded the class with the `static` becomes unreachable.  But this can only happen *after* your code has reached a point where nothing could possibly notice that the object is GC'd!
2. Something has used "nasty reflective tricks" to assign `null` to the `static final`.  (Yes, it can be done ...)
3. Something is subtly corrupting the heap; e.g. some buggy JNI / JNA code.

Note that since you are (apparently) *observing* the effect of the object being GC'd, it *CANNOT* be a direct result of the classloader being GC'd.  Something else must have happened to make it possible for the classloader and the `final static` to be GC'ed ... if that is what is actually happening here.

---

Actually, I suspect that your problem is not GC-related.  Rather, I suspect that your service is dying due to an unchecked exception that is not being logged.  The default behaviour for uncaught exceptions on threads other than "main" is to silently ignore them.

I suggest that you check that your service threads are logging all exceptions, either with a `catch` in the `run()` method, or in an "uncaught exception handler".

Answer (score 6):

In normal Java App (I'm not sure about Android), a *static final* referenced Object is GCed only when its proper ClassLoader is unloaded.

For example when having multiple web-apps in a container (such as Tomcat), undeploying each web-app, unloades application's ClassLoader, so application's *static final* referenced Object will be GCed. But objects loaded by other ClassLoaders (such as other web-app's ClassLoaders, common ClassLoader, boot-strap ClassLoader) won't be GCed.

So the answer to your question is: it depends on whether the ClassLoader is de-activated or not.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM uses a mark-sweep GC algorithm, which has to examine all the live refereces in the GC "root" locations (like all the objects in the current call stack). Each live object is "marked" as being alive, and any object referred to by a live object is also marked as being alive.

After the completion of the mark phase, the GC sweeps through the heap, freeing memory for all unmarked objects (and compacting the memory for the remaining live objects).

I'm going to say "no, the 'final' modifer doesn't help the GC reduce its workload".